# Error message retrieval in grass.read_command

Tags: python, grass-gis

I am writing a script in python and would like to get the error messages of the function grass.read_command for seeing why it is not working.

I found a webpage (http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/GRASS_Python_Scripting_Library) with a function that can be used for that:

```
def read2_command(*args, **kwargs):
   kwargs['stdout'] = grass.PIPE
   kwargs['stderr'] = grass.PIPE
   ps = grass.start_command(*args, **kwargs)
   return ps.communicate()
```

I saved the function as read2.py and imported it.

I run it:

```
grass.read2_command('v.db.connect', overwrite=True, map='C_01055500', table='C_01055500', key='cat', database='$GISDBASE/$LOCATION_NAME/$MAPSET/dbf/')
```

And get following message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'read2_command'
```

What do I need to do for the function to work ?

Comment: Shouldn't it be called as read2_command() rather than grass.read2_command()?

Comment: @markusN's comment is the answer. This shouldn't be an open question any more.